# Simple groovy function in jenkins pipeline does not work

Tags: curl, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I try to download a file using curl in `myFunction.groovy`

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def call(String URL = 'input') {
def command="curl '${URL}' --create-dirs -o output/data.jsp"
println command.execute().text
println "ls -ltrah".execute().text
}
```

Also tried:

```
def call(String URL = 'input') {
    echo "${URL}"
    echo "test"
    def command = ["curl", "${URL}", "--create-dirs", "-o", "output/data.jsp"].execute().text
    println "ls -ltrah".execute().text
}
```

This command even works in the execute script part of our jenkins slave:

```
println "curl 'http://xxx/data.jsp' --create-dirs -o output/data.jsp".execute().text
```

I call this in a jenkins pipeline with:

```
myFunction 'http://xxx/file.jsp'
```

The output is every time in a later stage:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'output/data.jsp'
```

What am I doing wrong?
The command works when I'm performing it in a bash command.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `.execute()` or anything like that in a Jenkins pipeline. If you need to shell out you should use the `sh` step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited**:

Based on the [Best Practices Guide](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/docs/BEST_PRACTICES.md) linked by mkobit, the [File Operations Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/File+Operations+Plugin) could help you out, check the [examples](https://github.com/jenkinsci/file-operations-plugin):

```
folderCreateOperation('test')
fileDownloadOperation('http://localhost/test.txt','','','test','test.txt')
```

**Original**:

I would not do this via curl, you can use the Groovy SDK:

```
File file = new File('test/test.txt')
file.getParentFile().mkdirs()
file.write('http://www.google.com'.toURL().text)
```

It is a one-liner if you don't need to create the parent directory:

```
new File('test.txt').write('http://www.google.com'.toURL().text)
```

To resolve your issue with curl, check the curl version and update if necessary.

Comment: In a Jenkins pipeline, you can not (and should not with Global libraries) do this.

Comment: @mkobit I think you can. :) Could you please explain what should not we do and why?

Comment: better for another question, but I'll add a few things here. The first one is with a default (or secure setup) these methods will be blocked. That is because the pipeline Groovy executes on the _master_ and not on an agent. If it was not security checked it could read files, change permissions, even call `System.exeit()` and terminate Jenkins. Blocking calls (like an HTTP call or a launched process) can really screw with resumability and the state. See the [best practices](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/docs/BEST_PRACTICES.md) docs for more

Comment: @mkobit It seems, there is a plugin for that, check my edited answer. :)

Comment: That is a reasonable approach - I try to avoid as many plugins as possible when running Jenkins instances because of the large amounts of compatibility issues that happen across them.